# Debian security kernel release?

Tags: debian, security, linux-kernel

In CVE pages like [CVE-2017-5754](https://security-tracker.debian.org/tracker/CVE-2017-5754) I see per major version two releases one of them marked with "(security)". What does this mean? In the example the kernel fix Stretch (security) was released earlier. How do I add the repository to have my server fixed earlier with this release? Or is this unwise because it is may be unstable or untested with security priority in mind? Is there a Debian page that explains it?

Comment: No, not for Wheezy!

Comment: What about Stretch, which was recently released just now and is more of my interest? in /etc/apt/sources.list I have: 
`deb http://security.debian.org/ stretch/updates main`                                                                                                                                              
`deb-src http://security.debian.org/ stretch/updates main`

I did not see the new kernel coming yet.

Comment: If you want stability; you are best using the tested kernel for the version you are currently running. Fixes that come out in a later kernel are backported to older kernels for older supported releases (with very few rare exceptions). Changes to /etc/apt/source.list et.al. take effect when you `apt-get update` and update repo lists, software loaded when you `apt-get upgrade`, `dist-upgrade` etc.

Answer (score 3):

“(security)” means the package is available in the security repositories, not in the main repositories. To get security updates for Wheezy, ensure you have

```
deb http://security.debian.org wheezy/updates main
```

in your repositories (typically in `/etc/apt/sources.list`). Updates made available in security repositories are ready for public consumption — you should upgrade as soon as you see one. *However* you should only use security repositories corresponding to the release you actually use — so only use the Wheezy repository above if you’re running Wheezy.

Packages are normally copied from the security repositories to the main repositories when a point release is made.

You’ll find relevant information on the [Debian security](https://www.debian.org/security/) page.